# If $f \in L^1(\Bbb R)$, then $\{f(x+n)\}\rightarrow 0$ for almost every $x$ in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f \in L^1(\Bbb R)$, then $\{f(x+n)\}\rightarrow 0$ for (Lebesgue) almost every $x$ in $[0,1]$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

This comes out of Richard Bass's real analysis book. I'm preparing for a midterm so any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly notice that,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|{\rm d} x\leq ||f||_1<\infty.$$
Now 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|{\rm d} x&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\ \int_{n}^{n+1}|f(x)|{\rm d} x  \\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}|f(x+n)|{\rm d} x  \\
&= \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}|f(x+n)|{\rm d} x,\,\, \text{by Fubini}\\
\end{align*}
Therefore the function $\sum_{n\geq 0}|f(x+n)|$ is almost surely finite. Hence it almost surely converges. So, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f(x+n)\rightarrow 0$$ almost surely.